# Django: How to load javascript from static files with template usage

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have a problem:

**in addWorkout.html:**

```
{% extends "workout/base.html" %}
{% block footer %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static js/addWorkout.js %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

**in base.html:**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>

{% block content %}{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

This will generate an error:

```
Invalid block tag on line 49: 'static', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

This error stems from the `src` attribute of the script tag in **addWorkout.html**. Apparently, django doesn't allow for the static tag to be inside of a block tag.

But how can I then import javascript from `static` by using the `script`-tag at the bottom of the `body` element?

EDIT:

If I change addWorkout.html to:

```
{% extends "workout/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block footer %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static js/addWorkout.js %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

I'll get the following error:

[image]

Comment: It can be simple `<script type="text/javascript" src="/static js/addWorkout.js"></script>` link without any braces, provided you defined `STATIC_ROOT` in your settings.py file

Comment: I believe you have to load static in the extended template too, please give it a try

Comment: PLEASE do not use a question to ask other questions. You should have opened a new question instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Child templates don't inherit the tags libraries loaded by their parents, you have to explicitely load `static` tags in your  addWorkout template. Note that [this is documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/language/#custom-libraries-and-template-inheritance)...

Comment: Adding `{% load static %}` to addWorkout.html results in another error. I've detailed the error in my edit.

Comment: You want `src="{% static "js/addWorkout.js" %}"` - else the template engine tries to parse `js/addWorkout.js` as a template or filter expression.

Comment: FWIW this is documented too : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-static - perhaps you could read the fine manual before asking questions ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the same error after removing the static tag from the extended template file, change the code as below and give it a try

```
{% extends "workout/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block footer %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static js/addWorkout.js %}">
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Replace your addWorkout.html with the above code

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, but it only results in another error. I've detailed this in my edit.

Comment: While giving the the path use double quotes for the js path only, 

 src={% static "plugins/parsleyjs/dist/parsley.min.js" %}